# Time complexity for dependent functions

Tags: time, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I have this method

```
public static void primeSort( String[] list, HashMap< Integer, ArrayList< String >> hm ){

  for( int x=0; x<list.length; x++ ){
    if( list[ x ] == null ) continue;

    String curX    = list[ x ];
    int    hashX   = primeHash( curX );

    hm.put( hashX, new ArrayList( Arrays.asList( curX )));

    for( int y=x+1; y<list.length; y++ ){

      String curY    = list[ y ];
      int    hashY   = primeHash( curY );

      if( curY == null || curY.length() != curX.length())  continue;

      if( hashX == hashY ){
        hm.get( hashX ).add( curY );

        list[ y ] = null; // if its an anagram null it out to avoid checking again
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which calls this method:

```
public static int primeHash( String word ){
  int productOfPrimes = 1;
  int prime[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 
    37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101 };

  for( char ch : word.toCharArray() ){
    productOfPrimes *= prime[ (int) ch - (int) 'a' ];
  }
  return productOfPrimes;
}
```

The objective is to take a list of strings and sort them into anagrams, returning a list containing anagrams grouped into list.

I'm trying to determine the time complexity, but it's a bit tricky.
primeSort will be worst case O(n^2) and best case O(n)

primeHash will run `m` times each time it's called where `m` is the length of the current string. I'm not sure how this will be analyzed and how it can be combined with the analysis for primeSort.

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be `O(n^2)` only in the first one, because of the nested loop. You call then `primeHash` once in every loop. There you also have one loop. Let `m` be the length of the String word. Then in WC you get `O((n*m)^2)`. However m will be most likely different, that's why I take the longest one, say `M` for the asymptotic analysis. Also `O((n*M)^2)`. Assuming that `M` in WC can be close to `n`:

You can end up with WC: `O((n^2)^2) = O(n^4)`.

In best case: You have only one loop iteration in the first function: `O(n)`. Then we make assumptions on the length of the each word. If they are with only one char then only one for-loop iteration in `primehash`, or simply constant. Therefore `O(1)`.

BC: `O(n)`.